# how to add standard error on cosinor2?

Tags: r, datatables, statistics, standard-error

Hi I have been working with the cosinor2 package on R and i was wondering if there is way to add standard errors for the mesor amplitude and acrophase. it would auto generate on cosinor1 as a table with the data but doesn't do the same cosinor2. is there a way to produce the errors ? Thank you in advance